# jquery ui autocomplete multiline results styling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

when I press down arrow thro' the results, its displaying the html elements like span,br, div. Is there a work around to style the results with out adding span, br, div to the results.Or how can I prevent results from show in the input field upon pressing down arrow. Only "Enter" key with dispaly the results in input field

Attaching the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried placing the other lines in a pseudoelement?

Comment: can you include a sample markup and the relevant js code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here this may help.

```js
 $(function() {

        var doctors = [{
            label: "Dr Daniel Pound",
            department: "Family Medicine, Medicine, Obesity",
            address: "3575 Geary Blvd Fl San Francisco CA"
        }, {
            label: "Dr Daniel Test",
            department: "Pediatrics, Pediatric Hematology",
            address: "1825 4th St Fl San Francisco CA"
        }, {
            label: "Dr Daniel Another",
            department: "Orthopedics",
            address: "1825 4th St Fl San Francisco CA"
        }];


        $("#doctor").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: doctors,

            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("#doctor").val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            }
        }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $("<li class='each'>")
                .append("<div class='acItem'><span class='name'>" +
                    item.label + "</span><br><span class='desc'>" +
                    item.department + "</span><br><span class='desc'>" +
                    item.address + "</span></div>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        };

    });
```

```css
.each{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
    padding: 3px 0;
    }
.acItem .name{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.acItem .desc{
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<body>
    <h1>Hello AutoComplete</h1>

    <input id="doctor" type="text" />


</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Look the oficial documentation

> http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

You can override the select and focus event

```
focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
    ...
    return false;
}
```

To display a single property of the object or a custom format, the #project is the input that you apply the autocomplete plugin